# Prevent url encode in response set cookie - nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, cookies, urlencode

In my node application, I am trying to change my cookie value with the below code. But when I set some cookie values I see it modified in my response header of browser.
Node code :

```
let nonEncodedString ='s%3A9Q8kumq4BgrHtJPM90ebhhl6OqChsxdp.x0uf93Hk5I03KWeF%2FFT3TM64riv3QAs'
res.cookie('connect.sid', nonEncodedString , { maxAge, httpOnly: true, overwrite: true });
```

But the header I get is

```
set-cookie: connect.sid=s%253A9Q8kumq4BgrHtJPM90ebhhl6OqChsxdp.x0uf93Hk5I03KWeF%252FFT3TM64riv3QAs; Max-Age=157680000; Path=/; Expires=Thu, 31 Jul 2025 11:28:35 GMT; HttpOnly
```

essentially
`s%3A9Q8kumq4BgrHtJPM90ebhhl6OqChsxdp.x0uf93Hk5I03KWeF%2FFT3TM64riv3QAs` 
is changed to
`s%253A9Q8kumq4BgrHtJPM90ebhhl6OqChsxdp.x0uf93Hk5I03KWeF%252FFT3TM64riv3QAs`. ie. '25' is being added.

I think it's happening because it is getting URL encoded.
I don't want that to happen since its changing the value I am sending and I don't have control to parse it before the browser sets it in the cookie.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you should set an `encode` function:

```
  res.cookie('connect.sid', nonEncodedString,
    { maxAge,
      httpOnly: true,
      overwrite: true,
      encode: v => v
    })
```

the default `encode` function is `encodeURLComponent`.

Comment: Can you provide any documentation for this solution? So in my case, if just leave the encode function as empty does it not encode at all with encodeURLComponent?

Comment: as i mentioned, the default value of `encode` function is `encodeURLComponent` function. when we set `encode: v => v` we are saying just return the input and don't change it. You can read more [here](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.cookie).